# I need CompareValidator control to accept date in format month/day/year

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource

I have the following template defined within DetailsView ( DetailsView is bound to object data source ):

```
    <EditItemTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtReleaseDate" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("ReleaseDate", "{0:d}") %>'>
       </asp:TextBox>
       <asp:CompareValidator ID="valReleaseDateType" runat="server"
               ControlToValidate="txtReleaseDate" Type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck"
               Display="Dynamic" > * 
       </asp:CompareValidator>
   </EditItemTemplate>
```

Assuming I enter into TextBox *txtReleaseDate* a date in format `month/day/year`, then upon clicking an *Update* or *Insert* button, a *CompareValidator* control complains that date format is not valid. But if I enter date in format `day/month/year`, then *object data source* throws an exception `Cannot convert value of parameter 'releaseDate' from 'System.String' to 'System.DateTime'`, while *CompareValidator* doesn’t complain.

I need the two controls to accept the same date format, so:

a) Since my DB stores date in format `day/month/year`, the best option would be for *ODS* to also accept this as valid date format. Can *ODS* be configured that way?

b)Can *CompareValidator* be configured to also accept `month/day/year` format?

thanx

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can set the CurrentUICulture of thread to en-GB format.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the web.config Globalization

I think 
 
format is "dd/MM/yyyy"

try putting "eb-US" one.
Gud luck.